# Getting simple date and time in android

Tags: java, android, date, time

How can I easily get date and time as integer values in Android?

Comment: This should more likely a Java question than Android.

Comment: sry, I forgot the java tag. Of course it is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the getTime() function of the java.util.Date class will do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

Show here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

To get the wall clock you just have to call:

> System.currentTimeMillis();